# Inserting user data from JSP into postgres database

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jsp

I created a registered form of user information with JSP. I want to insert user data into a table with userinfo in postgre database after submitting form. But instead of adding data into this table, it gives me errors. Please help me!

```
<%

    String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
    String lname = request.getParameter("lname");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String user = request.getParameter("uname");    
    String pwd = request.getParameter("pass");
    String pwd2 = request.getParameter("pass2");


    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/UserInformation", "postgres", "123456789");
    PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("insert into userinfo(firstname, lastname, email, username, password) VALUES ('" + fname + "','" + lname + "','" + email + "','" + user + "','" + pwd + "'");


    //ResultSet rs;
    int i = st.executeUpdate();

    if (i > 0) {
        response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
    }
%>
```

The output is:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at end of input
  Position: 142
```

Comment: Telling us the error you get is helpful

Comment: Also, why are you writing to a database from a JSP? Your logic should go in your controller, with the JSP just for the view.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, i do this with the help of this website [http://javaknowledge.info/login-and-registration-example-in-jsp-with-session/]. what way should use?

Comment: For learning purposes it's fine, however it's preferred to separate your data processing from your data presentation. http://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-model-view-controller/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (This is a comment, but i can't comment because don't have 50 points)

You must know, that scriptlets are a bad practice when you work with JSP. When code keep in mind the software development principles, like DRY (don't repeat yourself), SRP (single responsibility principle) and more. You have mixed your views with domain model, never do that. The only thing that you get when doing this is:

- Poor scalability
- Poor maintenance
- Spaghetti code

So, you need to re-structure your application by adding some layers (controllers and model).

- Create a access data abstract layer for communication with your data (eg., dao, repository).
- Create a controller for yours views.
- Use JSTL in your views to avoid scriptlets.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations.. it was so useful.. i understand that should improve my knowledge in MVC. :-)

Comment: @ShokouhDareshiri: you also should read the JDBC tutorial on how to *properly* use a `PreparedStatement`. The way you do it defeats the whole purpose of it.

Comment: Dear @a_horse_with_no_name, what is my mistake? However, the program works well.

Answer (score 0):

You have an sql syntax error remove the comma and single quotation(`,'`) at the end of your insert query

```
int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into userinfo(firstname, lastname, email, username, password, city, province, country) VALUES ('" + fname + "','" + lname + "','" + email + "','" + user + "','" + pwd + "','" + city + "','" + province + "','" + country + "'");
```

In addition use PreparedStatement instead of Statement to avoid sql injection.

Comment: Thank you.. i did what u said.. but, it didn't work :(

Comment: you still have syntax error ,before executing the query just print the query then copy that query run it in you database GUI tool to get the exact part of query where you have error